# Get the image number x of product gallery instead original product image

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm always getting crazy with product image of woocommerce.

Usually I find a compromise but this time is hard to find it.

I need to show a rectangular image ( height > 3 x width ) and if I use it as product image in the gallery the result is a super zoom and I don't like it.

For solve the problem in the past using Divi, I create a custom product page and I put an image instead product image.

But now I switched out from divi for several problems, and this problem has come out.

So my idea was:

-I set a a square product image with white background
-I find a way to show the first (if exist) image of the product gallery.

Is not a problem create a child theme with woocommerce templates, but I don't know how get the first image of the gallery

Any suggestion?

Comment: To get the first gallery image from the WC_Product Object, use `$gallery_ids = $product->gallery_image_ids();` and you will get the image url with `$img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_url( reset($gallery_ids), 'single-post-thumbnail');` …

Comment: Find the way! I used child theme with my custom product-image.php

After line 30 I change the code in:

`//$post_thumbnail_id = $product->get_image_id();
$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
$post_thumbnail_id = $attachment_ids[0];`